# Why is the button collapsed when I try to create a button group?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to create a `UIButton` group, horizontally.

So I created two buttons and created a new view to contain them. Then I add constraints to make it evenly placed horizontally.

But the two `UIButtons` just collapsed. The initial location of the buttons are the same but I don't think it matter.

```
- (UIButton*) getButtonWithTitle: (NSString*) title
{
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 80, 130.0, 40.0);

    button.layer.borderColor  = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    button.layer.borderWidth  = 0.5f;
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 2.0f;

    [button setTitle:title forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState: UIControlStateNormal];
    return button;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIButton *loginBtn    = [self getButtonWithTitle:@"Login"];
    UIButton *registerBtn = [self getButtonWithTitle:@"Register"];

    UIView *buttonGroup = [[UIView alloc] init];
    [buttonGroup setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    [buttonGroup addSubview: loginBtn];
    [buttonGroup addSubview: registerBtn];
    [self.view addSubview: buttonGroup];

    NSDictionary *viewsDictionary = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(loginBtn, registerBtn, buttonGroup);
    [buttonGroup addConstraints:
     [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-[loginBtn]-20-[registerBtn]-|"
                                             options:0 metrics:nil
                                               views:viewsDictionary
      ]];
}
```

**EDIT**

I followed `deimus` and removed the buttonGroup, but no change:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `buttonGroup` from this line and try again.

```
NSDictionary *viewsDictionary = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(loginBtn, registerBtn, buttonGroup);
```

Also remove

```
button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 80, 130.0, 40.0);
```

When your choosing to use the AutoLayouting makes no sense anymore to provide the manual coordinates

Comment: Have you tried to set `setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` on the buttons as well  ?

Comment: Also please remove the  `button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 80, 130.0, 40.0);` too, as you are using autolayouting makes no sense to specify manual coordinates

Comment: It worked, I set the frame mainly to get a height on the buttons

Comment: great ! updated the answer with correct instructions. if you need to specify some metrics for the buttons check the parameter `metrics` for `constraintsWithVisualFormat`